# What kind of encoding does posFlag requires?

Tags: go, static-analysis

How can I encode the position of the form `/pathto/file.go:40:32` which is returned by [`token.Position.String()`](https://godoc.org/go/token#Position.String) to a `posFlag` param required by [`ParseQueryPos`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle#ParseQueryPos) which looks like `/pathto/file.go:#550`.

Why?

I'm using the [`Oracle`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle) tool to do some static analysis. I need to run [`Oracle.Query`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle#Oracle.Query) which requires a param of type [`*QueryPos`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle#QueryPos). The only way to get [`*QueryPos`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle#QueryPos) is using [`ParseQueryPos`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle#ParseQueryPos).

Comment: https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/oracle/pos.go#L28 says the #550 is a byte offset, so it looks like you need to walk through the file, count bytes in the first 39 lines (including the newlines separating them), and add 31 (assuming file.go:1:1 is byte 0).

Comment: Ah, and there's a `token.Position.Offset` so you don't have to do all that!

Answer (score 1):

[The source to `tools/pos.go`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/4f8578d2c095328e9192e9d0b0ea335c6ea3e9a5/oracle/pos.go#L28-L30) called by ParseQueryPos says

```
// parsePosFlag parses a string of the form "file:pos" or
// file:start,end" where pos, start, end match #%d and represent byte
// offsets, and returns its components.
```

If you really had to convert from `line:column` strings, you'd look at the file contents and count up bytes (including newlines) leading to that line:column. But since you're working with a `token.Position`, it looks like you can get what you need from [`token.Position.Offset`](https://godoc.org/go/token#Position).

Comment: if Pos is byte offeset I'm wondering why we have a Pos type and don't just use Offset. Now I've found File.Pos https://godoc.org/go/token#File.Pos

Comment: [`token.Position`](https://godoc.org/go/token#Position) and [`oracle.QueryPos`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/4f8578d2c095328e9192e9d0b0ea335c6ea3e9a5/oracle/oracle.go#L138) each carry extra information that's useful in their respective contexts, which seems like enough justification to me.

Comment: Sounds fair enough to me. Any idea how to get the offset out of file:line:column ? ``oracle.Query.Describe``[0] provides just that so I no longer have access to ``token.Position.Offset``.  [0] https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle/serial#Describe.Pos

Comment: By hand: open the file, split on new lines, count total bytes in preceding lines (i.e., first 42 if string specifies line 43; add 1 byte per line assuming split stripped out newlines), add the column number, subtract 1 because :1:1 is byte 0 not 1. If speed were an issue (not likely) you could keep file contents around for faster counting after first use. There must be some better way, maybe worth digging around for an API that will give you an offset, but if you have to do that it's not too hard or too much code.

Comment: If you posted a *separate* question about the *overall task* you're trying to do, someone more familiar with these packages might be able to help. Other people here likely know more than me about these particular packages--I'm just telling you what I can figure out "blind".